# Can I use SQL Server Management Studio Express to connect to an MSDE database?

Tags: sql-server, msde

Is it possible to use SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 to connect to an MSDE database?

Comment: All good programmers are lazy, you know... so I figured it would be quicker to ask on SO than to actually try it... :) But seriously, I don't have access to the software to try it myself at the moment.

Comment: which software do you need, you can download the SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

(I've nothing else to add!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, why not upgrade to SQL Express 2005, which is the replacement of MSDE.

Comment: ...or SQL Express 2008, which is the replacement of SQL Express 2005 :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 also.